Terraform often tries to update kubernetes_secret with a resource "id"
I have many clusters with many secrets in each cluster. I am using Terraform to manage these clusters.
Every now and then when I run a plan when there are no changes of any kind to the code, terraform shows that almost all of the "kubernetes_secret" resources must be updated to add an "id" usually constructed of "namespace/secret_name". Here is an obfuscated example:
# module.some_module.kubernetes_secret.secret_resource will be updated in-place
~ resource "kubernetes_secret" "secret_resource" {

    id   = "my_namespace/secre-name"
    # (4 unchanged attributes hidden)

    # (1 unchanged block hidden)
}

I couldn't find the probelm nor the solution, so I ended up applying the plan and essentially nothing changes, but it's annoying that it happens every now and then.
Anybody has an idea what's going on?
Many thanx.
PS: The only correllation I noticed, is that this usually happens when someone else runs terraform in their local environment and updates the "main" branch. As far as I can tell it's harmless, just annoying.

Where do you store your state file? Locally or remote in S3 bucket?

state file is stored in an S3 bucket, I see that you voted the quesion down, could you clarify how I can improve it?
